# C# and CLR features confusion, what feature deserves to be described strictly as C# feature?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I've got to write few words about C#, generally piece of cake? No!

I've searched through various internet resources and books and what i got is kind of headache. For example **Garbage Collector** some sources says that this is C# feature, other that CLR got this feature and C# along with all other .NET languages got it by default. Ofcourse, my vote on CLR but there are lot other things that bring confusion, like **avoiding explicit code conversions**. Maybe i've got bad books and resources... so maybe someone would suggest some place where in clear way is said about C#

Second thing are origins of C# syntax, again few choices and nothing clear, other language combo by each other author. C, c++, Java, that's ok but VB6 and Delphi, i have doubts. And again features origin from these languages is mixed up with c# but in fact it is not clear if it is C# or CLR feature

MTH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GC is provided by the CLR

C# is everything that the language spec states, and no more.

Some of the more-interesting things that are actually C# features:

- iterator blocks [yield return]
- anonymous methods / closures / lambdas [the syntax, not to be confused with expression trees]

But anything that relates to the code you type, but which isn't directly provided by either the CLR or the framework is a language feature. Other languages may implement them too, of course...

- using [try/finally/Dispose]
- lock [Monitor.Enter/try/finally/Monitor.Exit]
- foreach [GetEnumerator()/while/[Dispose]]
- extension method resolution
- query syntax ["where pred" to .Where(x=>pred) etc]

(these are just a few examples of course; and again - other languages are at liberty to also provide these features!)

Answer (score 3):

The GC itself is a CLR feature, but the C# language assumes that it's running on a platform with garbage collection - without defining the exact semantics.

It's a tough thing to pin down precisely, but a rough rule of thumb is "if it's well defined in the language specification, it's a C# feature."

If you could give some more examples of *features* to categorise ("avoiding explicit code conversions" isn't a language feature, unless you want to give some more detail) it would help.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR is a development platform, a runtime environment, supporting managed code written in one of the .NET languages, of which C# is one. Garbage collection is a CLR feature. As are Code Access Security and Just In Time compilation of your managed code.

Answer (score 0):

You may the C# Language specification. Here are the references:

1. [C# Specification (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx)
2. [Standard ECMA-334 C# Language Specification](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Language_Specification)

Answer (score 0):

> Second thing are origins of C# syntax, again few choices and nothing clear, other language combo by each other author. C, c++, Java, that's ok but VB6 and Delphi,

Things C# got from VB:

- Properties
- Events
- For-Each loops
- Modules, declared as "static class" in C#
- Using default properties to make a class work like an array
- Late binding (C# 4)
- Integer overflow checks (C, C++, and Java cannot detect when you overflow an integer)
- P/Invoke for calling C++ dlls

In a way Optional Parameters (C# 4), but really that's from COM.